# Automatic conversation of log file

Tags: java, spring-logback

I want to convert log file in .gz , when it reaches his max index and want to keep file upto 60 days (Max history) in logback.

Log file will come in .gz when it reaches his max index value. And want to keep file upto 60 days with total capacity of 500 MB .
How can we do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please show us the code of what you have tried so far and the specific part you are getting stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a shell script to find these log files zip and arhive them. Use chron to schedule this task.

```sh
ARCHIVE_DIR=/path/to/archive/dir
ARCHIVE_FILE=$(data +"%Y-%m-%d").tar.gz
find logs -type f -iname *.log -mtime -1 | xargs tar -czf $ARCHIVE_FILE
mv $ARHICVE_FILE $ARCHIVE_DIR/$ARCHIVE_FILE
```

You can add this script to your chron tab

```
* 1 * * * /path/to/your/backup_script.sh # run it ever morning at 0100
```

You can remove the old log archive with find commmand. This command also can be scheduled.

```sh
find /path/to/archive/dir -type f -iname *.tar.gz -mtime -60 -exec rm {} \;
```